# Is it possible to send the 'new user set password' email when activating a user via workflow?

Tags: workflow, user

I have found some indications that salesforce will send the 'new user set password' email when an inactive user is activated via the UI (though one may need to check the 'reset pwd and notify user checkbox - not sure!).

However, it appears that this does not happen when a user is activated via a workflow rule, as a user reported not receiving the email and, I was not able to find the new user email from salesforce in the email log files.

I dont believe there is any way to have a workflow rule trigger the new user email, but I'm asking in case there is an option, perhaps with process builder / flow.

The user case is that I'm creating inactive users via visual workflow, using FinancialForce HCM as the system of record.  There is a workflow to activate the user one day prior to their start date.  I would like this workflow to trigger the 'new user set password' email.

Comment: So far nothing declarative.  Welcome email is not possible except on new user creation.  Reset password email works using invocable method, but getting a GACK when calling the apex in a proces builder scheduled action (works fine as immediate action).  Will update once support finishes working through the bug.